# `colClasses=c("Date",...)` gives error

Tags: r, date, read.table

When trying to convert the first column as date format using `colClasses=c("Date","numeric")` I keep getting the following error:

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  scan() expected 'a real', got '2012-01-03'
```

The first line looks like:

```
 data[1,]
        Date   Price
1 2012-01-03          85.40
2 2012-01-04          87.41
3 2012-01-05          88.69
4 2012-01-06          87.34
```

I have read the date as:

```
data<-read.table("file/data.txt", header=T, quote="\"")
```

I have searched in the internet, but could not find out what is wrong with my code.
Can someone give me a hint how I can solve this?

Comment: It is about this error message for me...

Comment: Please show the first few lines of your text file.

Comment: I think @Roland meant a `head` of the raw data file. Also, the full `read…()` call would be helpful.

Comment: I have added the read...

Comment: I cannot solve it. I will just replace the first column like: data[,1]<-as.Date(data$Date)

Comment: I have no idea if it's actually the way you wrote it in your code but it is `colClasses`, not `colClassses` as you wrote in your question.

Comment: Sorry, in my code I used the correct version `colClasses`

Comment: Ah ok. Just wanted to rule that out. Maybe you can show the actual line of code that raised this error. Right now, with what you provided, it's very difficult to guess what went wrong.

Comment: I don't understand why, but I think the question will be closed soon... I don't think the other question is a duplicate of mine